# hibernate , cant find ServiceRegistry class

Tags: eclipse, hibernate

I am trying to run this
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_examples.htm
it blows up on

```
factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

so I followed the instructions on how to do it in version 4

```
   private static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory() throws HibernateException {
       Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
       configuration.configure();
       serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
       sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
       return sessionFactory;
   }
```

but it cant find ServiceRegistry, this fails

```
import org.hibernate.ServiceRegistry;
```

and indeed it's missing from the jar files which I imported from the /hibernate-search-4.4.2.Final I downloaded, i.e. it's not in hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar

Comment: it should be in org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry.

Comment: thanks vinyak,
I think I needed 

    import org.hibernate.service.*;

Comment: i have provided a jar below in my answer. check it and let me know. Dont do org.hibernate.service.*;. Not a good thing target for specific classes only instead of *.

Comment: refer this, it may help:
[Please follow this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640619/hibernate-serviceregistrybuilder/35853289#35853289)

Answer (score 3):

Use `hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar`